# Symfony2 Mmoreram GearmanClient fails to load

Tags: php, symfony, gearman

I'm facing some problems with the GearmanBundle, since after the process of installation succeeded, I can find all my jobs and workers:

> $ app/console gearman:worker:list
>
> @Worker:
>
> HeloBundle\Workers\PushWorker
>
> callablename:  HeloBundleWorkersPushWorker
>
> Jobs:
>
> - ## 1
>
>   name: sendPushJob
>
>   callablename: HeloBundleWorkersPushWorker~sendPushJob
>
> @Worker:  HeloBundle\Workers\EmailWorker
>
> callablename:  HeloBundleWorkersEmailWorker
>
> Jobs:
>
> - ## 2
>
>   name: sendMailJob
>
>   callablename: HeloBundleWorkersEmailWorker~sendMailJob

As you can se, my gearman is installed on php:

> $ php -i | grep gearman | grep enabled
>
> gearman support => enabled

But when I call this:

```
try
 {
                $gearman = $this->container->get('gearman');
                $gearman->doBackgroundJob('HeloBundleWorkersPushWorker~sendPushJob', json_encode(array(
                        'tags' => $tags,
                        'message' => $message,
                        'all' => $all
                    )));
                $flash['type'] = 'notice';
                $flash['message'] = 'Success.';
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $flash['type'] = 'warning';
                $flash['message'] = 'Error.';
            }
```

It returns me this message:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "GearmanClient" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement for "Mmoreram\GearmanBundle\Service\GearmanClient"?" at /var/www/stage/vendor/mmoreram/gearman-bundle/Mmoreram/GearmanBundle/Service/GearmanClient.php line 90 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException(code: 0): Attempted to load class \"GearmanClient\" from the global namespace.\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for \"Mmoreram\GearmanBundle\Service\GearmanClient\"? at /var/www/stage/vendor/mmoreram/gearman-bundle/Mmoreram/GearmanBundle/Service/GearmanClient.php:90)"} []

The bundle can't load the native GearmanClient() on global scope. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: To ensure that the GearmanClient is available, and to remove the Mmoreram bundle from equation, I'd suggest writing a simple connection test, without the bundle, that creates a client, adds an endpoint and then does a `ping` to the server. There's some sample code on the GearmanClient::ping manual page. Further, I'd then put that code into a namespaced class and also making sure that works before moving on.

Comment: Actually, I already tested it and it runs normally. The only place that it break, is the GearmanClient.php from Mmoreram GearmanBundle.

Comment: I found it.

It seems the apache was pointing to a different conf.d.

Thank you for the help